# How to pass anti forgery token to react via asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I call my jsx file via the cshtml like so:

```
@model viewmodels
@Html.React("CreateStuff", new {
options = Model.KeyValues})
```

My jsx file contains a form which I'd like to POST back to my controller. However, the controller has a ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. How can I pass in the token from mvc land to react??

Answer (score 1):

You should to include in your view this row:

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: @DylanCzenski , yes

Comment: Any idea what to do if you are making multiple submits (without a form) from the page without refreshing it (mixing react + Razor). I've included the token in a header and I validate that using a custom attribute but it only validates successfully on the first post and from the second one on validation fails.